# freeradius One password for all user

Tags: freeradius

I am trying to implement IPSK using freeradius in Meraki. In freeradius users config file, I have to define mac-address plus tunnel-password. Is there a way to define tunnel-password once for all defined users?

#### Example my file right now

> a483e******* Cleartext-Password := "a483e*******"
>          Tunnel-Password = password
>
> f0189******* Cleartext-Password := "f0189*******"
>          Tunnel-Password = password

Here I have to define tunnel-password with every user/mac-address. Is there a way where I can define Tunnel-password once and pass a reference of that to user/mac-address defined

Answer (score 0):

At the bottom of your users file you can add the

```
DEFAULT Auth-Type := Accept
        Tunnel-Password = everyonegetsin
```

so if anyone enters this tunnel password when authenticating to your SSID then they get to join the network. Run your FreeRADIUS in debug mode freeradius -X you get a better picture of what is being passed to the server.

The idea of IPSK is so all users get a unique password to encrypt traffic, this way is not really achieving that goal.

Ideally you would want the server to deliver a Tunnel-Password to your accepted user/mac-address same behavior as the ISA.

https://documentation.meraki.com/MR/Encryption_and_Authentication/IPSK_with_RADIUS_Authentication look for step 4 in the using IPSK to authenticate against a Cisco ISE server graphic.